# Understanding definition of induced representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If we have $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $U$ an $\mathbb{F}H$-module, $U\otimes_{\mathbb{F}} \mathbb{F}G$ is an $\mathbb{F}G$-module defined by
$$(u\otimes \alpha)\cdot g=u\otimes (\alpha g)$$ for $u\in U, \alpha \in \mathbb{F}G$ and $g\in G$.

Moreover, $I_{U}=\langle u\otimes h\alpha - u\cdot h\otimes \alpha \mid u\in U, h\in H, \alpha \in \mathbb{F}G\rangle$ is an $\mathbb{F}G$-submodule. Finally, we define $$U\uparrow_{H}^{G}=(U\otimes \mathbb{F}G)/ I_{U}.$$

If $\phi$ is a character of $H$, I would like to understand the character afforded by $U\uparrow_{H}^{G}$.

I know that a basis of $U\uparrow_{H}^{G}$ is $\{b \otimes r + I_{U}\mid b\in B, r\in R\}$ where $B$ is and $\mathbb{F}$-basis of $U$ and $R=\{r_{1},\cdots,r_{n}\}$ is a set of representatives of the cosets of $H$ in $G$.

So in order to understand the induced character, first I need to know the induced representation (denote it by $\rho$) matrix.

To simplify the example, assume that $U= \mathbb{C}$. So it suffices to know the images of $1\otimes r_{i}+I_{\mathbb{C}}$ for $i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$. How can I calculate the coefficients of that images with respect to the basis of $U\uparrow_{H}^{G}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the discussion of induced characters in Lederman's "Introduction to Group Characters" to be a concrete introduction, where everything is described in terms of block matrices as opposed to induced modules.

Comment: Thank you! I have read it, but I still don't understand by that induced character is equal to the character afforded by $\mathbb{C}\uparrow_{H}^{G}$.

Comment: Do you understand what happens when $U$ is a trivial $H$ module?

Comment: No, sorry. I am getting quite confused. For example, if I take the character $1_{H}$, the image under $\rho(g)$ of $1\otimes r_{1}+I_{\mathbb{C}}$ would be $1\otimes r_{1}g+I_{\mathbb{C}}$, and I suppose that I need to use that $g=hr_{i}$ for some $i$ to know what is exactly that, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Inducing the trivial character of $H$ to $G$ gives the character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets of $H$. I suggest you read Lederman's book again until this is clear, it is the crucial concept, I think. Once you understand this, consider how to induce a one dimensional character of $H$ to $G$, and then finally consider an arbitrary character.